# PhpStorm и watcher Babel, как установить и настроить?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, babel

## Установка

Через консоль `PhpStorm` выполняю установку: `npm install --save-dev babel-cli`, установился в корень настоящего проекта.

## Настройка

В `Settings > Tools > File Watchers` создаю новый watcher с настройками:

**Program** - `C:\SERVER\domains\react.loc\node_modules\.bin\babel.cmd`.

**Arguments (дефолное)** - `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --out-dir dist --source-maps --presets env`.

**Output paths to refresh (дефолное)** - `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --out-dir dist --source-maps --presets env`.

## Тестирование

Создаю `test.js` с простым кодом для тестирования:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`PhpStorm` выдает ошибку - `Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "js"`

**Что делать?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установить preset `'env'`:)
Сам по себе babel не делает с кодом ровно ничего - он просто копирует исходный файл в `-out-dir`. Для того, чтобы он компилировал es2015 код в обычный javascript, необходимо установить набор плагинов и пресетов. Базовая функциональность доступна в пресете `babel-preset-env` - именно его вы передаете компилятору в качестве одного из аргументов (`--presets env`)

Устанавливается он командой `npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev`
для работы с ReactJS еще понадобится [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/).
Документацию по babel можно почитать здесь: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation (там нужно выбрать *CLI*). Вот [тут](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling#setting-up-babel-file-watcher) еще описана настройка file watcher в WebStorm

Comment: Установил все пакеты в папку проекта, они установились в папку `node_modules`, далее watcher-у указал файл `\node_modules\.bin\babel.cmd`, после этого выдает ошибку:

cmd.exe /D /C call C:/SERVER/domains/react.loc/node_modules/.bin/babel.cmd js\app.js --out-dir dist --source-maps --presets env
SyntaxError: js/app.js: Unexpected token (2:4)
  1 | ReactDOM.render(
> 2 |     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    |     ^
  3 |     document.getElementById('root')
  4 | );

Comment: к списку пресетов в *Arguments* надо добавить `react` - https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/: `--presets react, env`. А лучше вообще не передавать пресеты в командной строке, а настроить `.babelrc`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Извините за небольшой оффтоп, но, возможно, вам больше подойдет [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Создать проект через него очень просто:

```
npm create-react-app projectName
```

Запустить сервер для разработки:

```
npm start
```

Билд для продакшна:

```
npm run build
```